# How can I access JwtBearer authentication handler configuration in a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Core web application configured to use JWT bearer tokens for authentication:

```cs
// Setup.cs
// ...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services
        .AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://known.authority.url";
            });
}
// ...
```

The app has a controller action where it can receive JWTs signed using the same key information in the body of a POST request.

```cs
// TokenController.cs
// ...
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionAsync()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var jwt = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

I'd like to validate the JWT received in the controller action using the same validation parameters and signing keys configured in the bearer token authentication handler. (Ideally without duplicating the configuration for the controller action.)

How can I access the authentication handler's `JwtBearerOptions` `Configuration` properties in the controller action?

I've confirmed that `JwtBearerHandler` is a registered service in `HttpContext.RequestServices`, but its `Options` property is always `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: ASP.NET registers an `IAuthenticationHandlerProvider` service that can be used to retrieve an authentication handler by its scheme.

So, after modifying the `Startup.cs` file to include an authentication scheme for the JWT bearer handler:

```cs
// Startup.cs
// ...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(
            authenticationScheme: "MY_AUTH_SCHEME", // NEW
            options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://known.authority.url";
            });
}
// ...
```

Use the authentication handler provider service and its `GetHandlerAsync` method to get the handler and its options:

```
// TokenController.cs
// ...
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionAsync()
{
    // NEW
    var provider = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();

    // NEW
    var handler = await provider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext, "MY_AUTH_SCHEME") as
        AuthenticationHandler<JwtBearerOptions>;

    // NEW
    var jwtBearerOptions = handler.Options;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var jwt = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        // NEW
        var tokenValidationParameters = jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters;

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```